# Joining recent database rows in PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, row

Let's assume I have a MySQL structure like this...

```
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| tdate        | tuser              | tvalue            |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 11:16:48     | John               | 10                |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 11:16:38     | John               | 40                |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 11:16:28     | Lisa               | 50                |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 10:16:48     | Lisa               | 20                |
+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

and a php query like this:

```
<?php
$username =  'test';
$sql=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 20");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $tuser= $row['tuser'];
    $tvalue= $row['tvalue'];
    $tdate= $row['tdate'];
    ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $tvalue; ?>" class="message_box">
        <?php echo $tdate; ?> -
        <?php echo $tvalue; ?> -
        <?php echo $tuser; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
} 
?>
```

This currently lists the mysql table by each row like this:

```
2016-02-22 11:16:48 - 10 - John
2016-02-22 11:16:38 - 40 - John
2016-02-22 11:16:28 - 50 - Lisa
2016-02-22 10:16:48 - 20 - Lisa
```

I would like to see it like this:

```
2016-02-22 11:16:48 - 50 - John
2016-02-22 11:16:28 - 50 - Lisa
2016-02-22 10:16:48 - 20 - Lisa
```

Meaning that loop would have to sum up values in cases where the new row was created within 60 seconds (for the same user).. Lisa has two rows, but since there is one hour timestamp difference it would have to be listed as usual... It would need it to update automaticaly, meaning that it would show value of 40 for John initially, but after 10 seconds when the new row would be added it would have to update to 50 accordingly. There is also the issue of MYSQL QUERY LIMIT of 20 which could break up rows that were inserted within 60 seconds and give false total value calculation.. I know it's a hard one, but does anyone has a simple solution for this?

Thanks to Asur I currently have this:

```
SELECT ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tdate) DIV 60) AS time,tuser,SUM(tvalue) 
FROM t 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY_HOUR FROM tdate),tuser 
ORDER BY tid DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

but the problem is that if the last database row is JOHN, he will not be listed out last if there is already one John row above that in the same hour..

```
IF I HAVE: 
JOHN 10 
GEORGE 10 
GEORGE 10 
JOHN 10 

It will list: 
JOHN 20 
GEORGE 20 

And it should be the other way arround, where the last row counts: 
GEORGE 20 
JOHN 20
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to do it directly in the sql query as follows:

```
SELECT ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tdate) DIV 60) AS time,tuser,SUM(tvalue)       
FROM t
GROUP BY time,tuser
ORDER BY tid DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

This is long way better in terms of optimization and spent time.

Comment: Thanks for your effort :)... It successfully groups rows, but the time element does not work.. This solution sums up tvalue for the user in all rows.. I would like it to group it only for the timeframe of 60 seconds for example... That would mean that the same user would be listed out multiple times if there are other users in between time-wise..

Comment: Ok,I haven't seen that part, as guidance I would tell you to check [MYSQL intervals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: Yes sorry forgot to change it :) Is it completly functional?

Comment: It is a nice work arround.. But still not all rows within 60 seconds are grouped together.. It returns me two entries for the same user, even though all entries are less than 60 seconds apart (from the first timestamp for that user)..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104169/discussion-between-asur-and-120382833).

Comment: If I expand the timeframe even further another issue is again with the order.. Since the timeframe is long enough to list every user only once I can see that the last user listed is not the last one by tid or last tdate.. The problem might be GROUP BY time, tuser (because ROUND function takes the first tdate of each user instead of last tdate)...

Answer (score 0):

replace this query:

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 20
```

with this:

```
SELECT tdate , sum(tvalue), tuser FROM t 
group by tuser, DATE_FORMAT(tdate , '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i') 
ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: I appreciate this.. It works for me, but would you know how do I specify 60 seconds or a different timeframe if I want to change it?